# VS Code JavaScript Autocomplete with ESLint

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

Here is my code and it works as expected.

```js
function Afunction(v) {
    this.v = v;
}
Afunction.prototype.vlog = function () { console.log(this.v); };

function extend(props) {
    for (const key in props) {
        const prop = props[key];
        Afunction.prototype[key] = prop;
    }
}

extend({
    someOther: function () { console.log("someOther"); },
    someMore: function () { console.log("someMore"); }
});

var obj = new Afunction();
obj.vlog();
obj.someOther();
obj.someMore();
```

and output

```
some value
someOther
someMore
```

But in my VS Code show only the `vlog` in autocomplete suggestion. `someOther` and `someOther` not display there.

[image]

I learn about the extend function in `jQuery`. I try to implement it in my flavor. But I face this auto complete issue there are so many function property in my object so if autocompletion work it will be great. Otherwise I have to write all the property function `Afunction.prototype.someOther` like this.

I see there are so many `.ts` file in `ESLint` folder if there are any way to make a map/interface  file, so I once add all props there and it show me suggestion.

Comment: Javascript Intellisence is not executing any code, it is a static code analyzer, maybe you can create a `mytype.d.ts` file

Comment: can you provide doc link please, I google about this too many but not found :-)

Comment: have a look at the npm package `@types/vscode`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ESLint statically analyzes your code to quickly find problems. Autocomplete in VS Code are done by VSCode **intellisense**, and this can not run code it work statically.

You May follow these documentations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/javascript-intellisense?view=vs-2022

VSCode Supported JSdoc: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html

You may use `@typedef` like bellow.

```js
/**
 * @typedef  {Object} SpecialType - you doc here
 * @property {Function} someOther - you doc here
 * @property {Function} someMore  - you doc here
 */

/* All your code above place here */

/** @type {SpecialType} */
var obj = new Afunction();
obj.someOther();
obj.someMore();
```

[image]

**NOTE:** VSCode currently not support `@memberof` otherwise we also may use this. https://jsdoc.app/tags-memberof.html